# Basis in Linear Algebra $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

When you are trying to determine if a certain matrix of column vectors is a basis, when you prefer Gaussian elimination do you need to bring the matrix to row echelon form or reduced row echelon form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The echelon form is enough. The columns that have leading ones are the linearly independent ones, and the ones with no leading one are linear combinations of the others.